# Run tagged jobs Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, tags, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have set up my own runner in gitlab where I run my project's pipelines. I'm new to this of the Tags and I already informed myself a little about it.

But in my .gitlab-ci.yml I put a tag, for example build-v1.0.0 in build job. However, in order for the job to run, I need to put that tag in the Runner's log. **CI/CD Settings -> Runner Code -> Edit**

[image]

I have already registered some Tags in the runner, but I am trying to put a pattern so that it recognizes the prefix of N tags, something like that.

[image]

Is there a way that I can place the N tags I want without having to register them in the runner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, tags must match exactly. It seems like you are trying to use runner tags outside of their intended purpose.

**Runner tags**, not to be confused with git tags, are typically meant to be relatively static and describe general **capabilities of the runner**. This is because tags are (one way) how you make sure specific jobs are run by a specific runner. Runner tags are generally not used to describe the version of a particular software build.

For example, you might tag a runner with things like the operating system like `ubuntu` or `windows-server-2019`, or CPU architecture like `armv7` or `amd64` -- or whatever tags that describe environment/capabilities of the runner that are necessary for your builds. You typically would *not* use runner tags for every version of your software.